# Working with log files in R

Tags: r, encoding

I have a .log file that has an inconsistent data format.

The data looks something like this and is stored as "Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode" text:

```
2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING
2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS
     [XYZ 1000 T1]:1
2017-06-22 01:15:17.945 NOTHING 'D': 989
     [CASE] IN: [ID: 1010]33
     [CASE] IN: [ID: 2010]8
2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING
2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS
2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING
2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS
2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING
2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS

323133.....238813   76378    989899 000000000000
```

Now, I have several log files that follow this kind of pattern. I have tried scan() and read.table(), they both don't return data back in the format I expect it to do.

The data format I am expecting looks like this:

```
Date                          String
2017-06-21 00:00:30.483       START THIS THING
```

But, I have these line multiple times in the log files:

```
 [CASE] IN: [ID: 1010]33
 [CASE] IN: [ID: 2010]8
```

And this,

```
323133.....238813   76378    989899 000000000000
```

What would be the best way to approach this solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a raw sketch (ignoring the time part of your timestamp and column names) using base R without any performance optimisation (like using `data.table::fread` and the package `lubridate`):

```
log.data <- "2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING
2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS
     [XYZ 1000 T1]:1
2017-06-22 01:15:17.945 NOTHING 'D': 989
     [CASE] IN: [ID: 1010]33
     [CASE] IN: [ID: 2010]8
2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING
2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS
2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING
2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS
2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING
2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS

323133.....238813   76378    989899 000000000000"

log <- read.csv(text = log.data, sep = "\n", header = F)
log$timestamp <- as.Date(log[,1])
```

This results in:

```
> log
                                                 V1  timestamp
1    2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS 2017-06-21
2                                   [XYZ 1000 T1]:1       <NA>
3          2017-06-22 01:15:17.945 NOTHING 'D': 989 2017-06-22
4                           [CASE] IN: [ID: 1010]33       <NA>
5                            [CASE] IN: [ID: 2010]8       <NA>
6          2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING 2017-06-21
7    2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS 2017-06-21
8          2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING 2017-06-21
9    2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS 2017-06-21
10         2017-06-21 00:00:30.483 START THIS THING 2017-06-21
11   2017-06-21 00:00:56.400 SOMETHING ELSE HAPPENS 2017-06-21
12 323133.....238813   76378    989899 000000000000       <NA>
```

**Update 1:**

Since you found out that your log file uses the UTF-16 little-endian file encoding (checked with the `file` command of Linux/OSX in a terminal) you have to add the file encoding to `read.csv` to let R convert the file content correctly during reading:

```
log <- read.csv(file = "my.log", sep = "\n", header = F, fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, the files I have has a .log extension. I get errors like:  "line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls". Also, it only reads on element, and nothing else appears when I used read.csv with .log file.

Comment: Doe the .log files contain text or a binary format? If case of text content: Use `read.csv(file = "my.log", sep = "\n", header = F)` or show us your R code which fails.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: Use an text editor to open the file. If you work with Linux you can also open a shell and enter `file my.log` which shows the "guessed" file format ("ASCII" or similar in case of text files)...

Comment: I did this on Mac, got "Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF, CR, LF line terminators".

Comment: Should work, please add more information to your question (see my second comment below your question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152404/discussion-between-pj-and-r-yoda).