# How to split a large character into lines, based on time-stamp pattern matching

Tags: r

I need to parse the following character into 3 lines.
Each line starts with a timestamp, but can optionally span across multiple subsequent lines:

e.g.

```
x <- c('02-May-2017 10:10:41: some description
02-May-2017 10:10:42: some description
  some more
  and more
  02-May-2017 10:10:43: xyz')
```

A basic approach would be to search for the first match of the timestamp pattern, remember the start position and search for the next
timestamp starting from the end of the previous match, and extract the charterers in between.

Any idea if there is an efficient way to accomplish this.

btw, the required output is:

```
[1] 02-May-2017 10:10:41: some description
[2] 02-May-2017 10:10:42: some description some more and more
[3] 02-May-2017 10:10:43: xyz
```

Comment: This will not produce the results i am looking for. "each line should start with timestamp".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787444/4468078 for a partial solution of your problem (missing part is collapsing entries spanning over multiple lines into one line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
# read in line
x <- c('02-May-2017 10:10:41: some description
02-May-2017 10:10:42: some description
some more
and more
02-May-2017 10:10:43: xyz')

# remove line breaks
x <- gsub("\n", " ", x)

# regex pattern for timestamp
pattern <- "[0-9]{2}-[A-Z][a-z]{2}-[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}"

# split lines without time stamps
x.lines <- strsplit(x, pattern)[[1]][-1]

# corresponding time stamps
x.stamps <- stringr::str_extract_all(x, pattern)[[1]]

lapply(seq_along(x.stamps), function(i) {paste0(x.stamps[i], x.lines[i])}) %>% unlist()

[1] "02-May-2017 10:10:41: some description "                   
[2] "02-May-2017 10:10:42: some description some more and more "
[3] "02-May-2017 10:10:43: xyz"
```

Comment: Looks like we came up with similar solution ;)

Comment: I have tested it on the original file and it works fine, very elegant, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
res = strsplit(x, "\\s+(?=\\d{2}\\-)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]

[1] "02-May-2017 10:10:41: some description"                         
[2] "02-May-2017 10:10:42: some description\n  some more\n  and more"
[3] "02-May-2017 10:10:43: xyz"
```

You can excise the `\n` with a gsub afterwards like `gsub("\\n ", "", res)` or similar if desired.

This depends on none of the "some more" lines starting like `01-` or similar. If they do, the `?=` pattern can be extended to be more exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

#### stringr with regex solution

```
library(stringr)

y <- str_replace_all(x, "\\n", "")                                  # remove next lines
words <- unlist(str_split(y, "\\d+-\\D+-\\d+\\s+\\d+:\\d+:\\d+:"))  # uses regex to split string at date-like strings
words <- words[words!=""]                                           # remove empty string == ""
timestamps <- unlist(str_extract_all(x, "\\d+-\\D+-\\d+\\s+\\d+:\\d+:\\d+:"))      # extracts date-like strings

paste0(timestamps, words)
```

#### Output

```
[1] "02-May-2017 10:10:41: some description"                       
[2] "02-May-2017 10:10:42: some description  some more  and more  "
[3] "02-May-2017 10:10:43: xyz"
```

#### regex explanation

`\\d+` = digit(s)
`-` = `-`
`\\D+` = non-digit(s)
`\\s+` = white-space(s)
`:` = `:`

Comment: Thanks, it works fine with the example , but It breaks with the original file, since the timestamp is not unique.